# How browser cache determine that request is same or not?

Tags: http, caching, browser, browser-cache

I understand that the browser save the response, to return quickly at next `same request`.
But the question here is, what is `same request`? Does it mean that `same resource uri`  in the case of `Get` request?

What about the values ​​of headers included in the request or the content of the body?

I've seen that the `Cache-Control` header is also used for `Post` requests.

If so, is the standard for the same `Post` request determined by comparing the contents of the body?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

RFC 7234 [defines](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7234#section-2) the *cache key*:

> The primary cache key consists of the request method and target URI....
> If a request target is subject to content negotiation, its cache
> entry might consist of multiple stored responses, each differentiated
> by a secondary key for the values of the original request's selecting
> header fields.

The secondary key uses the headers listed in the `Vary` response header. See [section 4.1](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7234#section-4.1) for more detail.

> When a cache receives a request that can be satisfied by a stored
> response that has a `Vary` header field,
> it MUST NOT use that response unless all of the selecting header
> fields nominated by the Vary header field match in both the original
> request (i.e., that associated with the stored response), and the
> presented request.

To answer your specific questions:

> But the question here is, what is the *same request*? Does it mean the same resource URI in the case of a `GET` request?

Yes.

> What about the values ​​of headers included in the request or the content of the body?

The content of the body doesn't matter, and the headers only matter if they're listed in the `Vary` header.

> I've seen that the `Cache-Control` header is also used for `POST` requests. If so, is the standard for the same Post request determined by comparing the contents of the body?

Since the primary cache key consists of the URI and the method, two `POST` requests will have the same key if they have the same URI. However, as the standard [notes](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7234#section-2), "since HTTP caches in common use today are typically limited
to caching responses to `GET`, many caches simply decline other methods
and use only the URI as the primary cache key."

Comment: Just to note that Chrome does not support secondary keys and use just URI as a primary key and evict old variants when a new variant comes in. So even with just caching GET requests, you have only one response cached. Browsers do not reuse cache response if Vary is different, but it will not store multiple responses either. Firefox seems to do the right thing.